# Migracion de componente React a Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Estoy iniciando a migrar los componentes de mi aplicacion que fue creada todo con React/Tailwind a Typescript para evitar problemas antes de que escale.

Tengo un componente que es HeaderSection para ser especifico, que utiliza ScrollLink, pero cuando intento instalar la ultima version con npm, me da error y no hay forma de instalarlo, saben que puede ser?

El error es el siguiente.  lo instale manualmente ya que npm no me deja y cree un archivo react-slick.d.ts con la informacion.

```
declare module 'react-slick' {
  import React from 'react';

  export interface Settings {
    className?: string;
    centerMode?: boolean;
    infinite?: boolean;
    centerPadding?: string;
    slidesToShow?: number;
    speed?: number;
    autoplay?: boolean;
    autoplaySpeed?: number;
    responsive?: {
      breakpoint: number;
      settings: Settings;
    }[];
  }

  const Slider: React.FC<{ settings: Settings }>;

  export default Slider;
}
```

---

```
ERROR in src/components/Carousel/Carousel.tsx:12:19
   TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'Slider'.
       10 |
       11 | const Carousel: React.FC<CarouselProps> = ({ images }) => {
     > 12 |   const settings: Slider.Settings = {
          |                   ^^^^^^
       13 |     className: 'center',
       14 |     centerMode: true,
       15 |     infinite: true,
```

---

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link as ScrollLink } from 'react-scroll';

interface HeaderSectionProps {
  mainTitle: string;
  subTitle: string;
  buttonText: string;
}

const HeaderSection: React.FC<HeaderSectionProps> = ({
  mainTitle, subTitle, buttonText
}) => {
  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto px-4">
      <header className="flex justify-between items-center py-6">
        <div className="flex-1"></div>
        <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold">{mainTitle}</h1>
        <div className="flex-1"></div>
      </header>
      <section className="text-center py-20">
        <h2 className="text-6xl font-bold mb-6">{subTitle}</h2>
        <p className="text-xl mb-6">{buttonText}</p>
        <ScrollLink to="pricing" smooth={true} duration={500}
          className="inline-block"
        >
          <button className="bg-black text-white px-10 py-4 rounded-md hover:shadow-md transform hover:translate-y-1 transition-all duration-1000 ease-out"
            style={{ boxShadow: "0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 2)" }}
          >{buttonText}</button>
        </ScrollLink>
        <p className="text-sm mt-4">Designs you'll <span className="text-red-500">❤️</span>, guaranteed</p>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HeaderSection;
```

Comment: Sin saber qué error te da, es complicado adivinar qué está pasando te recomiendo leer [ask]

Comment: Puede que te falte instalar los tipos de la libreria, comparte el mensaje de error y edita la pregunta antes de que se vote para cierre

Comment: Hola!, como tienes las configuraciones en tu archivo tsconfig?